# Office VSTO generate Certificat?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, certificate, vsto

I don't know much about Certificates. This is the first time. So I know that if I create a Office VSTO Add In I need a Certificate to install it on other PCs.

My Project has a

```
MyProject_TemporaryKey.pfx
```

I know that this is a Test Certificate. 
But when I'm trying to install my VSTO on other PCs I always install that Certificate on the other PCs too but it doesn't seems to work. 
I alwasy getting this error:

```
Custom applications can not be used in this application because the certificate that signed the deployment manifest for MyProject or its location is not trusted.
```

That means that I need a real Certificate?
But as I know real Certifcates costs much. Isn't there a way to generate a Certificate that everybody must install befor they install my VSTO and then they can run it? I really need to test my VSTO on other PCs.

Thanks for everyone who can explain me what i have to do now cause I'm a real noob with Certificates.
Cheers

Comment: Install the PFX on the machine you want to install.

Comment: I already tryed it but i always get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it myselfe. There is a trick if you get this error.
Create a Installer like Installshield and Put your Add In in it. Now you can install it on every PC you want.